# Can Tor work here

Tags: configuration

I have bitmask vpn always on. How do I then configure orbot to use vpn? Is it possible on android? Tried searching but found nothing that helps me understand. Furthermore is the any special configurations need to run firefox thru tor after. Really could use the help understanding how to configurate all this together.
Thanks for all the help.
Silent Warrior

Answer (score 0):

If *"bitguard"* is actually making applications connect over the VPN, then simply starting Orbot would make it connect over the VPN.

To browse with Tor on Android, use the Orfox application which will use Orbot by default.